# LinearLayout scrollable with multiple ListView

Tags: android, listview

This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dip"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:text="@string/section_1" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_section_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dip"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:text="@string/section_2" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_section_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that when **first section** has many items and it takes up the whole screen, I can not scroll to see **second section**. With a quick search I just discovered that I can not use `ListView` within `ScollView`.

Is there any way to leave this `LinearLayout` scrollable so I can see all sections that can be added? I need something similar to the *iOS UITableView*, several sections and headers.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: For see all section all listView android:layout_height="Fixed size" without wrap_content...

Comment: @MdAbdulGafur doing this I can not scroll the entire screen to see second section. Need anything more in `LinearLayout`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, just to have a list with multiple sections, what I could do to solve my problem was quite simple:

I left just one `ListView` and created a class `CustomAdapter`. And added items with different types:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

HashMap map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("type", "section");
map.put("title", "Section 1");
listItems.add(map);

map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("type", "item");
map.put("title", "Item A");
map.put("detail", "Detail A");
listItems.add(map);
```

Set adapter to my `ListView`:

```
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(context, R.layout.result_list, listItems);
ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.resultlist);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

In my `CustomAdapter` I set a different style for each type, section or item. Note that I just want something to differentiate items in a `ListView`.

Still accept suggestions for this problem if my solution is too ugly :)

Answer (score 0):

Use layout_weight="1" and layout_height="0dp" for both ListViews which will split your entire screen into two parts, so that you can see both the sections. If you have to show TextViews as Headers on top of listviews, then take two linear layouts with above said weights and inside Linear Layout, place textview and listview with Vertical orientation.

Comment: Thank you for reply. You meant `layout_height`, right? Ok, I did this, but now I have my screen split and both `ListView` are scrollable. If possible I would like to be able to scroll the entire screen, and each `ListView` show up without having to scroll all individually.

Comment: unfortunately that is not possible as Android doesn't support Scrolling View inside a ScrollView. it doesn't shown an error but still it yields in bad User Friendly UI